# How to move an object to a position?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm trying to move an object to the coordinates `48.7, 51.07, 102.8`, but it does not move. I did some test to make sure that "OnMouseDown" works, and it does, I think it could not be finding the object "upgradeone".

```
public class click1 : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject Upgradeone;
    GameObject cube;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Upgradeone = GameObject.Find("upgradeone");
        cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        Upgradeone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(48.7f,51.07f,102.8f);
    }
}
```

Comment: if object isnt found it should be thrown nullpointerexception. what's happening? do you know what's the purpose of OnMouseDown? check here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm certainly seeing some issues in the way you're using Unity and with the script you have.

You script to move the object should be attached to the object you want to move. This means you won't need to use `Find` to statically locate the object you want to move, it'll be the object the script is attached to. That means you can simply use the `this` keyword to access the object to be moved.

Further, you're setting the local scale of the object, not the position. You'll want to modify `this.transform.position` to adjust the position of the object in the game world.

Finally, you're only taking action in `OnMouseDown` this only triggers once when the object is clicked. If you want to [move the object](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) over time, you'll have to use the `Update` method. You can still use `OnMouseDown` to trigger the start of the movement.

As an example, this script will move the object to the coordinates when clicked:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class click1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 1;
    public Vector3 target = new Vector3(48.7f,51.07f,102.8f);
    private bool moving = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(moving) {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown(){
        moving = true;
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted it to be instantaneous and activated from a different object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class click1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public Vector3 target = new Vector3(48.7f,51.07f,102.8f);

    void OnMouseDown(){
        if(objectToMove != null) {
            objectToMove.transform.position = target;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you set `objectToMove` by dragging the object from the hierarchy into the inspector for your trigger object, specifically the `objectToMove` field of the `click1` script.

Or, you can set in the `Start` method with the [`Find`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) method, but I'd recommend against it. Setting the `objectToMove` in the editor is a cleaner way of dealing with this and doesn't hard code strings into your scripts.

Comment: I just want it to instantly move there, and is there a way to move it when the script is not attached to it?

Comment: Sure, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to move an object in Unity:

- `obj.transform.Translate(theTranslationVector)`
- `obj.transform.position = newPosition`

In the code you are using, you set the object's `localscale`, which obviously won't move the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets transform.localScale but you want transform.localPosition